# Rider says all project files are not part of the project

Tags: rider

This problem is kind of confusing. I opened a Unity project, added a new script, and opened it in Rider. Analysis stopped working. It says it's not supported, for every single script. I pressed the view IL button, and it says that every file is not part of the project.

Comment: *and opened it in Rider*: what exactly did you do to open the script?

Comment: @Gorohovsky I double clicked on it in the Unity window

Answer (score 0):

Does your Unity Project have the Rider plug-in installed?  If you open the package manager (Windows->Package Manager) you should see JetBrains Rider Editor with a green check mark next to the version number:

[Unity Package Manager with Rider Editor plugin installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEHpI.png)

If you don't see it you should be able to install it, by ensuring the the Packages filter in the top left says "Unity Registry" then searching "Rider" in the search bar in the top right, selecting the "JetBrains Rider Editor" on the left, and clicking "Install" on the bottom right.